# Keep Me Signed In message missing during login if using msal.js

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

**Context**

I'm developing a browser application that uses msal.js library to allow Azure Active Directory accounts to access our website. The application has the clientId and the scopes properly set and it uses *loginRedirect* and *acquireTokenSilent* successfully.

**Problem**

The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to keep the session open because I don't see the Keep Me Signed In message (KMSI) so I can not answer 'YES' and make the *AADSSO* cookie persistent. For that reason after the login process, if the browser is closed I need to log in again.

**Expectation**

If I'm redirected to microsoft login from my website using msal.js library, I expect to see the KMSI message to enable persistent session (which for some reason I can see if I go directly to login.microsoftonline.com)

[image]

Sorry for the spanish: It says Do you want to keep the session open? No / Yes

**Question**

How can I enable KMSI with msal.js ?

Comment: That's interesting.. Do you have a Web app that uses e.g. OpenID Connect authentication with AAD? If you login with that, does it prompt you for KMSI? I'm thinking that since your front-end is a public client / using implicit grant flow, this could be just expected behaviour. But I'm not sure.

Comment: If I browse microsoft login page directly, it does. But if I'm redirected from msal.js library it does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of not seeing 'Keep me signed in' login message when using msal.js is because when the library builds the URL to perform the login, it contains a query string item called x-client-Ver that changes the microsoftonline.com login flow. 
If you remove that item from the URL (&x-client-Ver=1.1.3 for example), you can see the 'Keep me signed in' message.

The solution is to manually patch the library removing this until Microsoft fixes it. Like that: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/982/commits